# Cypress - How to use response body in another request header

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a function that will return a token

```
var accessToken;
function TestToken(){
    return cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "https://site/token",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: {
            client_id: '1234',
            client_secret: '1234',
            audience: 'https://site/api/v1/',
            grant_type: 'credentials'
        }
    }).then(response => {
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const rbody = (response.body);
        var tokenPattern = "(?i)\"access_token\":\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"";
        const authToken = rbody.access_token;
        accessToken = authToken
        cy.log(accessToken);
        resolve(accessToken);
        return accessToken;
    })
});
```

I call that function in another cypress command, as I need to use the token in the authorization header

```
Cypress.Commands.add("ResetPwd", () => {
    const authToken = TestToken();
    cy.log(authToken);
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "https://site/api/v2/users/1234",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'authorization': 'Bearer '+authToken,
        },
        body: {
            password: 'Test4321',
            connection: 'DB',
        }
    });
});
```

When I execute the command, I don't see the token being used. Instead I see `"authorization": "Bearer [object Object]"` in the request.

In the TestToken funtion, I added `cy.log(authToken);`, to verify it was correctly grabbing the token. The cypress test failed saying

> CypressError: cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and
>   sync code.

but I could still see the correct token in the console.

Here is the cypress test I am trying to run

```
describe('Token Test', function() {
    before(() => {
        cy.ResetPwd();
    })
    it('Go to website', function() {
        cy.visit('https://site/login')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`functions` is synchronous so in moment of call it the result will be equal `Promise`, promise is object and when you try to stringify object (by + operator) you get `[object Object]`.

After some time promise will be resolved and value in `authToken` variable will be correct.

To fix it is suggest use `Cypress.Promise` like in example id cypress docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Basic-Promise

Comment: I'm not sure my usage of promise is correct. In the TestToken function, `cy.log(accessToken);` shows the correct string. However, `cy.log(authToken);` in ResetPwd is an empty value.

Comment: authToken in this example will not be correct, try `TestToken().then((authToken) => { cy.log(authToken) })`; instead of `const authToken = TestToken();`

Comment: Trying that gives me this error `CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.`

Comment: Right, that's because cypress commands are promises. Please try something like this: `Cypress.Commands.add("ResetPwd", () => { return TestToken().then((authToken) => { ... }); })` The goal is to make flat structure of promises.

Comment: This should be marked as an answer - thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the `TestToken()` function is a promise and resolves asynchronously causing the authToken to be [ object Object ]

You could use `async/await` and the code should work fine.

Add `async` before the arrow function and use `await const authToken = TestToken()`

Comment: When adding async/await, my test is failing with this error `CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, after lots of work using cy.task:

```
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/where/you/retrieve/your/token',
            body: {username: user, password: password},
            failOnStatusCode: true
        }).then((response) => {
            cy.task('setToken', response.body);
        });
```

then:

```
cy.task('getToken').then((token) => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/your/protected/endpoint/here',
        headers: {
           authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        failOnStatusCode: true
    }).then((response) => {
        expect(response.something).to.eq(something.else);
    }); 
});
```